# What are the advantages of CMMI over ISO 15504 (SPICE), and vice versa?

Tags: development-process, quality-assessment

Trying to write a paper where I have to compare process improvement models to implement for a hypothetical avionics software development company.

From researching, it seems that CMMI and SPICE are pretty similar and both derived from CMM. The problem I'm having is I'm finding it difficult to distinguish when you would recommend one over another.

So far I've managed to find out that:

- SPICE is slightly cheaper than CMMI
- SPICE is recognised more in Europe
- CMMI is recognised more in US and required for US military contracts
- CMMI takes longer

Is there anything better that can distinguish between these?

Answer (score 2):

I apologize for being a bit crass here, but if you are writing a paper to compare the process models and the only thing you came up with so far what amounts to cost, location of acceptance, and time then I think you need to dig in a bit deeper.

I would recommend comparing the models themselves. What are the similarities and (esp.) the specific differences in the processes and in particular the differences in what is required to recognize improvements in the processes.

Which is "better" is subjective depending on your specific needs, and possibly for regulatory requirements for your fictitious avionics company.

Answer (score 0):

"SPICE is recognised more in Europe" -> I would not by any means say that. I live and work in Europe and CMMI is far more known and acknowledged than Spice.

In fact, for me that's the main reason for choosing CMMI. Both are good approaches to process improvement but CMMI is the de facto standard.

Answer (score 0):

CMMI helps advance the state of the practice, accelerate the development and adoption of best practices, and provide solutions to the emerging needs of businesses around the world.As we found both Spice and CMMI are good approaches, CMMI is more effective and trendy process with high standards. To grab or compare more information refer KPMG International Blog or sites , who are the leading expertise in [CMMI Development](http://www.kpmg.com/in/en/services/advisory/performance-technology/itas/pages/spi.aspx).